# Replace 16.04 with 20.04, keep my /home... and /boot?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, software-installation, 20.04, reinstall

Below I am showing my current disk/filesystem.
I mean to replace my current 16.04 with a fresh install of 20.04 in `/dev/sda6`, keeping my `/home` partition.

**What precautions should I take (besides backing up my data), regarding:**

**1. /home**.
For instance, I have currently the `user1` that is created during installation and two more. Is it enough to use the same username during installation of 20.04 to get `user1` home dir read by 20.04?
How to get 20.04 read the home dirs of the other two?

**2. /boot**

**3. Etc.?**

---

My current state:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for user1: 
Disk /dev/sda: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7fa54200

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2  *          2048    1955839   1953792   954M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3          1957886  750000127 748042242 356.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4       1078964224 1465147391 386183168 184.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5          1957888   66406399  64448512  30.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6         66408448  164063231  97654784  46.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        164065280  750000127 585934848 279.4G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   26M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/sda6        46G   18G   26G  41% /
tmpfs           7.9G  423M  7.4G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       923M  179M  681M  21% /boot
/dev/sda7       275G  242G   20G  93% /home
tmpfs           1.6G  136K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: This video worked well for me while upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04 without losing home folder. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD7Rp8Jt1rE

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend a **fresh install**. This clean your entire system and makes sure that, from the start, everything is set up as the Ubuntu developers have intended and tested.

Because you have a separate home partition, you can **keep your user data** on the system. I, however, do recommend not to take over the existing user system configuration of your existing home folder, except for very specific applications such as Thunderbird mail if you use that.

That can be achieved with following procedure.

1. **Boot to a live session** using the installation USB.
2. **Mount** your hard drive containing your **home** partition
3. **Rename** your current home folder (of the "first created user" with root power) from e.g. `user1` to `user1_old`.
4. **Start installation**. Select "Something else" as installation type, because you need to assign partitions yourself.
5. In the **partitioning screen**, a) assign your old root partition as the new *root* partition. Make sure the checkmark "format" is checked so that volume will be fully erased before installing the new system. b) assign your current *home* partition as the /home partition, but make sure to *uncheck* format. Thus data on that partition will remain.
6. **Proceed** with installation, and have your `user1` created as first user. This will create a fresh `user1` directory in the home partition.

This way, you will have an entirely fresh and clean installation. You can now very quickly place your user data back by moving files from Documents, Videos, Music, etc. folders in `/home/user_old` to the respective folders in the new `/home/user`. Optionally, selected hidden configuration folders can be moved from the old home.

When, a few weeks later, you are comfortable nothing else is needed from the `user_old` folder, you can delete it.

Comment: And before doing any of the above, **MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR HOME FOLDER**.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade this way:

1. Make a **backup**
2. Press **Alt+F2** and type in `update-manager -c -d`  into the command box.
3. Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '20.04' is available.
4. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

This way it should upgrade only your system, without loosing any files or other data.

Another way is via Live USB. You should choose the option to erase ubuntu 16.04 and install 20.04, keeping your files.

Comment: You cannot upgrade from a 16.04 directly to 20.04!

Comment: I would rather have a fresh install, instead of an upgrade... In the long run, it's usually cheaper.